# Apple Pay Merchant Validation with Spring Boot (Reactive)

Tags: spring-boot, jvm, certificate, spring-webflux, applepay

We have a spring boot backend trying to perform merchant validation and retrieve a payment session for Apple Pay. Following [these](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/configure-app-capabilities/configure-apple-pay-on-the-web#create-a-merchant-identity-certificate) steps from Apple, we were able to generate a merchant validation certificate. When I try to create a Keystore programmatically and add the certificate issued by Apple for use in my web client call, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())

val certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")

val keyStore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType())
keyStore.load(null)

val merchantValidationInputStream = FileInputStream(<PATH_TO_CERT_FROM_APPLE>)
val merchantValidationCert= certificateFactory.generateCertificate(merchantValidationInputStream)
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("applePayMerchantValidationCert", merchantValidationCert)

val sslContext = SslContextBuilder
                            .forClient()
                            .trustManager(trustManagerFactory)
                            .build()

val httpClient =   HttpClient.create()
                .secure { it.sslContext(sslContext) }

val webClient = builder
    .clientConnector(ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
    .baseUrl(<VALIDATION_URL_PASSED_FROM_WEB>)
    .build()

return webClient.post()
    .bodyValue(<REQUEST_BODY_WITH_MERCHANTID_DISPLAYNAME_INITIATIVE_INITIATIVE_CONTEXT>)
    .retrieve()
    .toBodilessEntity()
// For now I am just trying to get this call working and not doing anything with the response. 
// Using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/apple_pay_js_api/requesting_an_apple_pay_payment_session#3199965 
// as reference for the request body structure
```

Could I get some help figuring out what might be happening here?

Tools/Framework Versions

- Spring Boot: 2.7.6
- Kotlin: 1.7.22
- Java: 17 (Adoptium)

Things I have tried:

- Used keytool to import root and intermediary certs from [Apple](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/) (adding them as trusted certs)
- Tried converting the .cer file from Apple to a .pem file
  before adding it to the web client call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After working on this with @janani-subbiah we determined the following was the solution.

For full instructions please visit the Apple Pay docs but I wanted to give a high level overview of the cert transitions we needed to make as well as the Spring Boot code to use it. Also note, you can do most of the cert changes with OpenSSL but I just used the Mac Keychain tool for simplicity.

1. Create merchant id in Apple console
2. Create CSR on Mac Keychain app with ECC and 256 bit key pair
3. Create payment processing cert in Apple Console using the CSR from
   previous step (this is sent to our payment processor, not used in
   our code)
4. Add all the frontend domains that will use this Apple Pay config in
   the Apple Console
5. Download the Apple verification file for each domain and deploy it
   to the path Apple specifies on your frontend to complete verification
6. Create CSR on Mac Keychain Access app with default settings
7. Create the merchant identity cert in the Apple Console (this is the
   cert that needs to be sent via our backend for mutual TLS)
8. Download that cert, open it in Keychain Access on Mac and go to your
   login keychain, select "My Certificates". You should see the
   merchant cert there and it can be expanded to see the private key.
   Select both the cert and private key then right click and select
   export 2 items. In the export make sure to select p12 format and set
   a secure password that will be used by the backend.
9. Finally, in a Spring Boot app you need the following to use the cert.

```kotlin
data class PaymentSessionRequest(
    val merchantIdentifier: String = "merchant.your merchant identifier",
    val displayName: String = "Any Apple Pay Display Name",
    val initiative: String = "web",
    val initiativeContext: String = "Fully qualified domain of the frontend"
)

val pass = "Password you set when exporting the p12 cert in step 8" // Should be set as a secret and exposed as an environment variable.
val inputStream = javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/merchant_id.p12") // Should be mounted as a secret file and loaded from there.
val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")
keyStore.load(inputStream, pass.toCharArray())

val keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509")
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, pass.toCharArray())

val context = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
    .keyManager(keyManagerFactory)
    .build()

val client: HttpClient = HttpClient.create().secure { spec -> spec.sslContext(context) }
val connector: ClientHttpConnector = ReactorClientHttpConnector(client)

val webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl("https://apple-pay-gateway.apple.com") // Should use validation URL passed in from the Apple Pay JS SDK and include IP address validation based on Apple's docs
    .clientConnector(connector)
    .build()

webClient.post()
    .uri("/paymentservices/paymentSession")
    .bodyValue(PaymentSessionRequest())
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono<String>()
    .doOnNext { logger.info("Apple Pay Session response: $it") }
```

Comment: Re *"After working on this with @janani-subbiah"*: What does it refer to? By which channel/method?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Sorry for the lack of context there, Janani and I work together. We were trying to solve this problem and came to StackOverflow to ask for assistance but continued to work on it after posting.

Answer (score -1):

Try Converting the certificate file from Apple (.cer) to PEM format using the OpenSSL to perform this conversion.

**Shell**
openssl x509 -inform der -in your_certificate.cer -out your_certificate.pem

Create a Java KeyStore and import the converted PEM certificate into it.

**Java Code**
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

```
// ...

String keyStorePath = "path/to/your/keystore.jks";
char[] keyStorePassword = "your_keystore_password".toCharArray();
String certificatePath = "path/to/your_certificate.pem";
String alias = "your_certificate_alias";

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(null, keyStorePassword);

FileInputStream certificateFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(certificatePath);
Certificate certificate = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(certificateFileInputStream);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry(alias, certificate);
keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(keyStorePath), keyStorePassword);
```

**Configure your SSLContext to use the KeyStore.**
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

```
// ...

String keyStoreType = "JKS";

KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword);

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
```

**Use the configured SSLContext in your HttpClient.**
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

```
// ...

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setSSLContext(sslContext)
    .build();
```

This should be resolving the `SSLHandshakeException` issue.

Also, replace the placeholder values in the examples which I have given above (`your_certificate.cer, your_certificate.pem, path/to/your/keystore.jks, your_keystore_password, and your_certificate_alias`) with the values from your application.

Comment: Thank you Sreeram for you response! Unfortunately I continue to run into my original issue with this solution. I created a KeysStore (had to enter things like my name etc), used it in the code you have above. I also couldn't use the SSLContext and CloseableHttpClient code because it wasn't compatible with Spring Boot.

But overall I tried this solution with some minor tweaks and had not luck. Anything I could be missing?

Comment: Hi, Sreeram Nair.  

Most or all of your last 11 answers appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Many also have comments indicating that they are wrong in some respect. Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.